# debugging powershell script file (PS1) from C#

Tags: powershell

We have created PS1 files.We are able to call the function in PS1 file from C# using Runspace,Pipeline etc.I am able to debug only upto "pipeline.Invoke()".

But now my question is whether it is possible to debug the PS1 file from pipile.Invoke()?
I mean Pressing F11 on "pipeline.Invoke()" can take me into the PS1 files? I basically want to debug the powershell script files from C#.

Answer (score 7):

It's possible, but not particularly feasible. You have to directly interact with the runspace's debugger events, and essentially build your own engine integrating that into Visual Studio. This would be quite a time consuming, which is why it hasn't been done.