# Debug Powershell script that is called by C# program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

In `Visual Studio 2017` (or any other version), I want to add a breakpoint inside a `Powershell` script (`*.ps1`) that is invoked at runtime by a C# program.

For example, I have this C# code:

```
using System.Management.Automation

var powerShell = PowerShell.Create();
powerShell.AddCommand("script.ps1");
powerShell.Invoke();
```

How can I add a breakpoint in `script.ps1` file that will be hit when `powerShell.Invoke()` is called ?

EDIT: I realize there's a similar 5-year old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466489/debugging-powershell-script-file-ps1-from-c-sharp), however a lot has changed since 2013 and possibly there's a way to do this now...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debugging powershell script file (PS1) from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19466489/debugging-powershell-script-file-ps1-from-c-sharp) or [How do I debug a powershell script executed from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787447/how-do-i-debug-a-powershell-script-executed-from-c)

Comment: Do 5 year old questions count as duplicates?

Comment: Why wouldn't they?  They're asking the same thing.

Comment: Because there were about 3 new version of VS and 3 new versions of Powershell since 2013. That question and answer refers to old (2013) software.